# optional array in avro schema

Tags: arrays, null, option-type, avro

I'm wondering whether or not it is possible to have an optional array.
Let's assume a schema like this:

```
{ 
    "type": "record",
    "name": "test_avro",
    "fields" : [
        {"name": "test_field_1", "type": "long"},
        {"name": "subrecord", "type": [{
         "type": "record",
         "name": "subrecord_type",
           "fields":[{"name":"field_1", "type":"long"}]
          },"null"]
    },
    {"name": "simple_array",
    "type":{
        "type": "array",
        "items": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Trying to write an avro record without "simple_array" would result in a NPE in the datafilewriter.
For subrecord it's just fine, but when I try to define the array as optional:

```
{"name": "simple_array",
 "type":[{
   "type": "array",
   "items": "string"
   }, "null"]
```

It does not result in a NPE but a runtime exception:

```
AvroRuntimeException: Not an array schema: [{"type":"array","items":"string"},"null"]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 39):

I think what you want here is a union of null and array:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"test_avro",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"test_field_1",
      "type":"long"
    },
    {
      "name":"subrecord",
      "type":[
        {
          "type":"record",
          "name":"subrecord_type",
          "fields":[
            {
              "name":"field_1",
              "type":"long"
            }
          ]
        },
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"simple_array",
      "type":[
        "null",
        {
          "type":"array",
          "items":"string"
        }
      ],
      "default":null
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use the above schema with sample data in Python, here's the result (`schema_string` is the above json string):

```
>>> from avro import io, datafile, schema
>>> from json import dumps
>>> 
>>> sample_data = {'test_field_1':12L}
>>> rec_schema = schema.parse(schema_string)
>>> rec_writer = io.DatumWriter(rec_schema)
>>> rec_reader = io.DatumReader()
>>> 
>>> # write avro file
... df_writer = datafile.DataFileWriter(open("/tmp/foo", 'wb'), rec_writer, writers_schema=rec_schema)
>>> df_writer.append(sample_data)
>>> df_writer.close()
>>> 
>>> # read avro file
... df_reader = datafile.DataFileReader(open('/tmp/foo', 'rb'), rec_reader)
>>> print dumps(df_reader.next())
{"simple_array": null, "test_field_1": 12, "subrecord": null}
```

Comment: Had the same issue with java lists, your answer has solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I get the same error. In my setup I'm trying to process a Avro file using MapReduce Java program. The job was successfully. The next stage of the datapipeline is to create a hive table (avroSerde) over the transformed data, The table also gets created successfully but when I try to query the table using hql, (which in turn executed a mapreduce Job), the job fails with a "Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable "